# Build a cpp file every time with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I want a file that contains the build date to be build every time.

After some research I have tried many different approaches, but I don't understand them fully. I thought the following code should work, but it doesn't. It is written in a `CMakeLists.txt` file which is part of many cascaded `CMakeLists.txt` files.

```
[...]
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
        src/software_version.cpp [...]
)
[...]

set(VERSION_FILE "src/software_version.cpp")
add_custom_target(build_software_version ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${VERSION_FILE})
#or
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${VERSION_FILE})
```

Edit:
I'm using the predefined __ DATE__ in a method in that file and I've found out that it wont be up-to-date if I don't build the file every time. If I just make a small change to the file so the file is beeing build again, the date is correct. I was hoping to achive that with the `touch` command.
So I was expecting to see the note that the file was build in the build-log. (An other file shows up there every time too)
At this point the first command compiles, but doesn't change anything. The second one throws an error at building time.
[error]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Cle.png

Comment: `touch` should work - it sets the "latest change date" to now. This should be visible on disk; is it?

Comment: It misses a dependency from `build_software_version` and `${PROJECT_NAME}`.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", you mean that you expect a no-change build to still bump the build date and that is not happening?

Comment: I meant `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} build_software_version)`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Makes sense. Would you mind to share the error you receive with us? Might be a problem of paths. You might try to use the absolute path to `software_version.cpp`.

Comment: adding `add_depencencies[..]` before or after makes it fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution with `add_custom_target` almost worked, there are just two things which need to be added:

1. the custom target is run from the build directory... where no source file with that name is to be found. Prefixing `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` fixes that. It would also be possible to set the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` parameter of [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).
2. a dependency needs to be added as pointed out by Jarod42 in the comments.

I believe the following code does what you want:

```
add_custom_target(build_software_version 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch src/software_version.cpp
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC src/software_version.cpp)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} build_software_version)
```

---

#### Some more thoughts

While the text above answers the question, it's not necessarily the best solution for the underlying problem. To have the current date compiled into the binary, I'd write the date into a file using CMake rather than relying on the `__DATE__` preprocessor variable. If done right, this would force rebuilds only once per day.

Comment: the existing `add_executable[..]` from the main stands in a differend file. do i need to change that for real? it doesn't look very friendly  `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.rc ${RCC_SOURCES})`

Comment: @Nick updated with your target names. Thanks for your feedback. Tell me if you spot any more issues.

Comment: It's working!!t Thank you so much   
but the target doesn't have to come before the library right?

Comment: interestingly it's building only every second time

Comment: Funny, it builds every time on my machine. Could be Windows' coarse time resolution... I have no idea, sorry. The order of targets is not important, although both have to be known for `add_dependencies` to work.